# Caching in Spring MVC output

Tags: java, caching, spring-mvc

I have a mobile App. I need to provide data read from a particular site. I'm using spring mvc as backend. The data from that site will change only after 2-3hrs. Till then I want to cache the fetched data and provide it to all the devices so as to prevent request to that site. What is the suggested method?

Comment: use any caching framework like EHCache,JCS,swarmcache

Answer (score 4):

You can use Spring 3.1 [caching abstraction](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html) and simply annotate the call fetching from external site with `@Cacheable`:

```
@Cacheable("StuffCo")
public Stuff fetchStuff() {...}
```

Also if your site only displays that cached data and does not add any dynamic content, you might consider web-layer caching. [EhCache](http://ehcache.org/) (which you will probably use for caching back-end) provides handy [Web Caching](http://ehcache.org/documentation/user-guide/web-caching) feature.

### See also

- [28.5.2 Ehcache-based Cache](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-store-configuration-ehcache)
- [Using Spring and Ehcache](http://ehcache.org/documentation/integrations/spring)
- [Caching Methods with Spring 3 Annotations](http://ehcache.org/documentation/recipes/spring-annotations)
- [`ehcache.xml` configuration](http://ehcache.org/documentation/configuration/configuration)
- [`EhCacheFactoryBean`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/cache/ehcache/EhCacheFactoryBean.html)
- [Integrating Spring and EHCache](http://byteco.de/2010/01/26/integrating-spring-and-ehcache/)

Comment: how do I set the cache time ...?

Comment: @AkhilKNambiar: `@Cacheable` is just an **abstraction**, you need a concrete cache storage, like EhCache. In EhCache you need to create a cache named `StuffCo` (in a file called `ehcache.xml`) where you can configure **everything**.

Comment: @AkhilKNambiar: See *See also* section of my post.